# Switching to tabBarController but no tab bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I apologize for asking two similar questions but I don't think I worded it correctly the first time and am still struggling to find the answer.

I am in a `viewcontroller` that is in a project containing a `tabBarController`. I want to switch from the `viewController` to one of the viewcontrollers contained in the `tabbarcontroller`. The problem is it either doesn't show up at all or if I present the normal `viewcontroller` there is no `tab bar`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2,viewController3);

}
```

I want to switch from my Tag view controller to FirstViewController

```
Tag.m 

-(IBAction)save:(id)sender{
FirstViewController*vc =[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.tabBarController.viewControllers popToViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

Update:

I solved this by adding my `ViewController` to a `TabBar` within my .m file then

```
[_tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
        [self presentViewController: _tabBarController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Thanks for the responses I got on this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `rootViewController` property of `mainWindow` of `AppDelegate` some thing like this.

```
AppDelegate * appDel = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDel.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

Enjoy..

Comment: Is this in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:? I have self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

Comment: thats ok you can do it. i have written this answer for use any where in application

Comment: In tag.m it's giving me an error "undeclared identifier tabBarController"  I've imported the appdelegate.h file as well :/

Comment: try - `[appDel.window setRootViewController:appDel.tabBarController];`

Comment: Thanks no errors from that. Just it's not switching. I have also tried putting it in the save function. I guess the [self.tabBarController.viewControllers popToViewController:vc animated:YES]; is just not happening

Comment: TabBar will not support popToViewController we have to try something else. Let me think about it.

Comment: you have written "I want to switch from my Tag view controller to FirstViewController" . What is "Tag view controller"?

Comment: Tag is the name of my ViewController